# How do I spy on a method from a sealed library class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, assert, spy

I have an analytics client that has a track method getting invoked when an event is received.

When I go to mock the class I get this:

```
 Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.
```

**Is there any way to spy on and verify parameters passed to a sealed class method?**

in JUnit you can more freely do a "spyOn(class.method)..."

How can this be done in C# or with Moq?

Code looks like:

```
  private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetry;

    public ClassToTest(TelemetryClient telemetry)
    {
        _telemetry = telemetry;
    }

 public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(EventMessage message, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var serviceNotificationEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceNotificationEvent>(message.Value);
            _telemetry.TrackEvent(AnalyticsConstants.EVENT_RECEIVED);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "Error processing event message");
        }
    }
```

Current Unit test attempt:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_ReceivedEventAnalytic()
    {
        Mock<TelemetryClient> _mockTelemetry = new Mock<TelemetryClient>();

        _serviceNotificationProcessor.ProcessMessagesAsync(mockMessageList);
        IDictionary<String, String> matchingMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       // build out matchingMap

        _mockTelemetry.Verify(t => t.TrackEvent("seamEventReceived", It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, string>>(), null), Times.Once());
    }
```

Comment: Heug can you add the code where you initialize _telemetry? It is a bit hard to talk about only knowing the variable name. Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: @KristianBarrett its just regular private variable going into a constructor, but i added it

Comment: `new Mock<TelemetryClient>()` is not possible because `TelemetryClient` cannot be inherited from (it is a `sealed class`). Moq works only by inheriting (or implementing as it is called for interfaces) the relevant type and supplying new implementations for the methods/properties/etc.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen im aware, thats why i mentioned all of that above in the original post/question. im looking for solutions despite this.